# MacOS+apache, CGI scripts give error 304

Tags: macos, apache, cgi

I'm trying to help a colleague get a test setup going on his mac so that he can run CGI scripts. I'm a linux guy, and he's not a server guy, so between us we're having trouble getting the most basic setup to work. Here's what we've done so far:

Install/enable apache:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Edit the file `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and uncomment this line:

```
#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

In the same file, edit the line beginning with with `Options` and add `+ExecCGI` to the list of options.

Install a sample perl CGI script test.cgi in `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables` and make it world-executable. Source code:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html> <head>\n";
print "<title>Hello, world!</title>";
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>\n";
print "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>\n";
print "</body> </html>\n";
```

When we go to the URL `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi`, the result is http error code 304, which means "not modified." This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It normally seems to have something to do with caching, which just doesn't seem relevant to our situation.

Nothing shows up in the apache error log. We can tell that apache was finding the script, because before we added the +ExecCGI option, the browser would display the source code of the script. We tried to check for problems with permissions, making sure that everything was world-readable and executable:

```
ls -ld /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 Sep  2 13:58 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables
ls -l /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  343 Sep  2 13:58 /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi
```

The owner and group of the script are the same as those of the directory in which the script lives, which seems reasonable.

Can anyone give any suggestions as to what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you call `/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/test.cgi` (like that) from the shell? What happens if you add a GET parameter to the URL, eg. `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi?test` ?

Comment: Can you also post the full verbatim response headers from some command-line client?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add an Options ExecCGI to your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf - add it to a directory specific stanza

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
  Options ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```